# Textile: how do I center all the text in the table cells?

Tags: textile

So... here is my table

```
| Locking | x | x | x | x |
| Public / Private | x | x | x |  Default: Private |
```

now, how do I change it so that certain columns are centered, or that every cell is centered? or just a single cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single cell is centered as following

```
|=. some-text |
```

For details see [documentation](https://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/#tables) or [User Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20150506213601/http://www.einfach-persoenlich.de/mt-doc/mtmanual_textile2.html#tables).

---

### Update

This is a table example tested on **github wiki**.

#### Whole table center

> table{text-align:center;}.

```
table{border:1px solid black; text-align:center;}.
|This|is|a centered table|row|
|This|is|a|row-row-row-row|
```

[image]

#### Single cell center

> |=. centered-cell-text|

```
table{border:1px solid black; }.
|This|is|a centered table|=. cell|
|This|is|a|row-row-row-row|
```

[image]

#### Single cell formatting

The cell must start with `{css code}.`  (mind the space).
[Outline Every Cell In Every Row Of A Table Using Textile Formatting](https://www.question-defense.com/2009/05/22/outline-every-cell-in-every-row-of-a-table-using-textile-formatting)

E.g.

```
|_{border:2px solid black}. Provider |_{border:2px solid black}. Text Email Address|_{border:2px solid black}. Verified?|
|{border:2px solid black}. 3 River Wireless|{border:2px solid black}. 10digitphonenumber@sms.3rivers.net |{border:2px solid black}. *Not Verified* |
```

Try textile in a sandbox: Sandbox: https://txstyle.org/

Comment: @TheLindyHop github uses a slightly modified MarkDown syntax(http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), not Textile

Comment: Is there a way to make all the cell boundaries to have **border:1px** and not just the table outline?